# Python fill string with formats with dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, format, zip, python-itertools

Say I have templates to fill with values in dict:

I have templates like this:

```
templates = [
   "I have four {fruit} in {place}", 
   "I have four {fruit} and {grain} in {place}",
   ...
]
```

With dictionary like this:

```
my_dict = {'fruit': ['apple', 'banana', 'mango'], 
           'place': ['kitchen', 'living room'],
           'grain' : ['wheat', 'rice']
          }
```

Say I have a sentence like this:

```
sentence = "I have four apple in kitchen"
```

Given this sentence, templates, and dictionary, 
I would like to know that sentence matched one of the templates and return values which it matched like this:

```
{'fruit': 'apple', 'place': 'kitchen'}
```

And similar to above if:

```
Input: "I have four apple and wheat in kitchen"
Output: {'fruit': 'apple', 'grain': 'wheat', 'place': 'kitchen'}
```

And it would be great if it can handle this too:

```
Input: "I have four apple in bedroom" 
Output: {'fruit': 'apple'}
```

Notice it only returns fruit and not bedroom since bedroom is not in the values of place.

Comment: What have you done to try solving this problem on your own?

Comment: using itertools.product to get all combination and using .format(**{combination}) to fill in but not sure how to get which keys were filled after that with

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turn your formatted strings into regular expressions:

```
import re

words = {k: '(?P<{}>{})'.format(k, '|'.join(map(re.escape, v))) for k, v in my_dict.items()}
patterns = [re.compile(template.format(**words)) for template in templates]
```

This produces patterns of the form `I have four (?P<fruit>apple|banana|mango) in (?P<place>kitchen|living room)"`. Matching these then provides you with your expected output:

```
for pattern in patterns:
    match = pattern.match(sentence)
    if match:
        matched_words = match.groupdict()
```

This is a very fast, O(N) approach to matching sentences exactly:

```
>>> import re
>>> templates = [
...    "I have four {fruit} in {place}",
...    "I have four {fruit} and {grain} in {place}",
... ]
>>> my_dict = {'fruit': ['apple', 'banana', 'mango'],
...            'place': ['kitchen', 'living room'],
...            'grain' : ['wheat', 'rice']
...           }
>>> def find_matches(sentence):
...     for pattern in patterns:
...         match = pattern.match(sentence)
...         if match:
...             return match.groupdict()
...
>>> find_matches("I have four apple in kitchen")
{'fruit': 'apple', 'place': 'kitchen'}
>>> find_matches("I have four apple and wheat in kitchen")
{'fruit': 'apple', 'grain': 'wheat', 'place': 'kitchen'}
```

If you need your templates to match *partial* sentences, wrap the optional parts in `(?...)` groups:

```
"I have four {fruit} in (?{place})"
```

or add `\w+` to the words list (in addition to the valid words), then validate `groupdict()` result against `my_dict` after matching. For the `in bedroom` case, `\w+` will match the `bedroom` part but won't be found in the `my_dict` list for `place`, for example.